# Consistent error management in R

Tags: r, error-handling

Once you've got the hang on your typical R error messages they're quite useful.

Nevertheless, I often find R's own error messages to be not as informative as I'd expect, so I usually end up writing some sort of customized error messages.

Now, I wonder if there's some systematic approach (or what would be the recommended best-practice approach) to this with respect to assigning unique error codes as well as additional information to specific errors.

I guess I'd like to build some sort of a hash table solution for errors where additional information can be stored and retrieved for each error. Would you use some sort of a "light" DB solution (e.g. SQLite) or solve this via a simple `data.frame` or `list` object that is stored somewhere (`.rdata`) and retrieved if needed?

### Homework

To be honest, I haven't done that much research on it yet. Though here's at least something ;-)

### Package [reportr](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/reportr/index.html)

I just found out about the **reportr** package and will check that out in more detail. Does anyone have experiences with that package or a similar one yet?

### Outline of my own approach (partly pseudo code)

```
myFoo <- function(x, ...) {
    tryCatch(
        x * 100,
        error=function(e) {
            record <- retrieveErrorRecord(e) # Does not exist yet
            # 'record' would be some sort of list or Ref Class Object

            if (!length(record)) {
                uid <- generateUid(e) # Does not exist yet
                msg <- paste(
                    "expecting arg 'x' to be of class 'numeric' (was '", 
                    class(x), "')", sep="")
                insertErrorRecord( # Does not exist yet
                    list(
                        uid=uid, 
                        message=msg, 
                        original=e
                    )
                )
                record <- retrieveErrorRecord(e)
            } 
            msg <- c(
                "myFoo/error:\n",
                paste("* Code:     ", record$uid, "\n", sep=""),
                paste("* Message:  ", record$message, "\n", sep=""),
                paste("* Original: ", record$original, "\n", sep="")  
            )
            stop(msg)            
        }
    )
}
```

That's how the message would look like

```
require("digest")
x <- "abc"
e <- simpleError("test error")
record <- list(
    uid=digest(e),
    message=paste("expecting arg 'x' to be of class 'numeric' (was '", 
        class(x), "')", sep=""),
    original=e
)
msg <- c(
    "myFoo/error:\n",
    paste("* Code:     ", record$uid, "\n", sep=""),
    paste("* Message:  ", record$message, "\n", sep=""),
    paste("* Original: ", record$original, "\n", sep="")  
)
> stop(msg)
Error: myFoo/error:
* Code:     e78e73054b93d2bf682df32845cd064d
* Message:  expecting arg 'x' to be of class 'numeric' (was 'character')
* Original: Error: test error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO one way would be to "translate" the current R error messages to something more fitting your needs. This could be done easily on the (currently down?) http://translation.r-project.org/pootle page. And it would require a lot of work/time...

But I think the standard R error/warning messages are quite straightforward, although really technical, but hey, aren't we programming or what? :)

But to be give an answer/hint on how this could be done (with some `regexp`), I have implemented something similar which might be worth referencing here in my [`eval.msgs`](https://github.com/daroczig/pander/blob/master/R/evals.R#L82) function (which is a helper for a more robust function called `evals` there).

This function works like `evaluate`, so evaluates given R commands are tries to catch possible informative/warning/error `messages` besides `stdout` **and** the returned raw R object. There I realized that the `syntax error` messages are quite lame in one line, so applied there the above `regexp` which is resulting in the below examples:

```
> x <- 'foobar'
> eval.msgs('x 100')
$src
[1] "x 100"

$result
NULL

$output
NULL

$type
[1] "error"

$msg
$msg$messages
NULL

$msg$warnings
NULL

$msg$errors
[1] "Unexpected numeric constant at character 3 in line 1: ` x 100`"


$stdout
NULL

> eval.msgs('x foo')
$src
[1] "x foo"

$result
NULL

$output
NULL

$type
[1] "error"

$msg
$msg$messages
NULL

$msg$warnings
NULL

$msg$errors
[1] "Unexpected symbol at character 3 in line 1: ` x foo`"


$stdout
NULL

> eval.msgs('x*100')
$src
[1] "x*100"

$result
NULL

$output
NULL

$type
[1] "error"

$msg
$msg$messages
NULL

$msg$warnings
NULL

$msg$errors
[1] "non-numeric argument to binary operator"


$stdout
NULL
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply! thanks man, I'll check it out this week. Seems like a good way to go!